# Coordinate array to layer using cheap-ruler

Tags: leaflet, mapbox, turf

I have calculated a destination from bearing/distance (feet) using cheap-ruler.js https://github.com/mapbox/cheap-ruler

Console.log() returns this array from the calculation..

```
[-87.36328091530362, 37.78808138412046]
```

I then am trying to add the result to the map using...

```
    var ruler = cheapRuler(35.2, 'feet');

    var bearing = document.getElementById('bearing').value;
    var distance = document.getElementById('distance').value;

    var calc = ruler.destination(lnglat, 0.1, 90);

    destlnglat = [calc[0], calc[1]];

    var myIcon = L.divIcon({className: 'css-icon'});

    // Pass array to layer...
    var destinationPoint = L.geoJson(destlnglat, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, destlnglat) {
            return new L.Marker(destlnglat, {icon: myIcon });
        }
    }).addTo(map);
```

Which returns no error in the console? How do I correctly pass back to L.geoJson()?

Edit: I got this working using the following..

```
function calculateDestinationFt() {

    var ruler = cheapRuler(35.2, 'feet');

    var bearing = document.getElementById('bearing').value;
    var distance = document.getElementById('distance').value;

    var calc = ruler.destination(lnglat, bearing, distance);

    var myIcon = L.divIcon({className: 'css-icon'});

    var m_coords = {
        lng: calc[0],
        lat: calc[1]
    };

    var destination = {
                        "type": "FeatureCollection",
                        "features": [{
                            "type": "Feature",
                            "properties": {

                            },
                            "geometry": {
                                "type": "Point",
                                "coordinates": [m_coords.lng,m_coords.lat]
                            }
                        }]
                        }   

    var destinationPoint = L.geoJson(destination, {
    pointToLayer: function (feature, lnglat) {
            return new L.Marker(lnglat, {icon: myIcon });
        }
    }).addTo(map);
}
```

But my results are waaaay off? I got these results pluging in a bearing:270 and distance 5280ft? Neither ft or bearing appear correct. AaAH!!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple answer!

You're got your bearing and distance around the wrong way. From the docs: https://github.com/mapbox/cheap-ruler#destinationp-dist-bearing

Quote:

**destination(p, dist, bearing)**

Returns a new point given distance and bearing from the starting point.

```
var point = ruler.destination([30.5, 50.5], 0.1, 90);
```

Comment: Haha. Omg. Thanks for pointing this out @Alex Leith.  Im surprised it provided any solution at all?  Here's what works... var calc = ruler.destination(lnglat, distance, bearing );